# How to delete elements from a List synchronously by Index?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I have a `List` of Cards, the `Card` is a class. And I have three hands to which each hand are dealt to four cards.

in the game inside the `onTouchEvent` I have to delete the touched card when it is in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, the problem is:

if the available cards IDs in a hand are as follows: 100,130,112,70 with respective indeces: 0,1,2,3. when I want to delete the touched Card the indeces reshuffle, for an example,

`(100,130,112,70)->(0,1,2,3) delete(1)==>130 will be deleted`

`(100,112,70)->(0,1,2) delete (2) ==> 70 will be deleted and NOT 112.`

`(100,112)->(0,1) delete (3) ==> an OUT_OF_BOUND exception will be thrown.`

How to avoid this,I tried to delete element by refer to each elements ratio among the list but it is complicated.

Comment: You should be deleting the card by the id.

Comment: @Luksprog yes, but also i woul need to refer to each card index

Comment: You should use the dataStructure like ArrayList<Integer> or something similar, that does not have index-value relation. Because you cardID is itself unique. So it will help you to directly delete the card by its ID, as @Luksprog has commented.

I guess you are currently using an array as your dataStructure.

Comment: you could use a HashMap with an int-key instead of a List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current implementation, you can simply delete from the list beginning with the highest index, moving to the lowest:

```
(100,130,112,70)->(0,1,2,3) delete(3)==>70 will be deleted.
(100,130,112)->(0,1,2) delete (2) ==> 112 will be deleted.
(100,130)->(0,1) delete (1) ==> 130 will be deleted.
```

However, you would probably be better off by storing your cards in a `Map` or ID to Cards. That way you could simply remove by ID without worrying about its index.

Answer (score 2):

See SparseArray (there are many of them)...If I got you right its exactly what you need.
It's basically kind of a hash map, but it has less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You could store cards internally in a Map - that way, keys (indices) will stay the same.

However, logic that picks index of card to be deleted is suspect - how come your code wants to delete index 3 when there are only two cards and why does index 2 get chosen when you want to delete card on index 1?

Comment: each Hand has four cards 0-3 and when the user picks a card to play, this card should be deleted